# How to console.log a <td> that has an ID. Getting ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, dom, console.log

Pretty much the title. There might be a solution somewhere but I am too dumb to word it properly. So sorry if that's the case.

```
<head>
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="test">Some random, text separated, by commas, that I will, try to separate, with filter.split(/, /);, sometime in the future </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
var testTd = document.getElementById('test');
console.log(testTd);
```

Can I make it so the console.log(testTd) output is:
"Some random, text separated, by commas, that I will, try to separate, with filter.split(/, /);, sometime in the future "

Getting "ReferenceError: document is not defined" error all the time.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. The `document` should always be defined. Sure, you [won't find the element when executing that script in the `<head>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1048572), but it should still work and log `undefined`, not throw a reference error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your script tag in the end of the body instead of the head

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Although why is that? Why won't it work in <head>?

Comment: The script is being loaded before the body, therefore the selected document doesn't appear to exist.

Answer (score -1):

This should to work with jquery:

```
$("#test").text();
```

Or you can use this too:

```
document.getElementById ( "tdid" ).innerText
```

Comment: I don't know jQuery so other comment was more helpful since the code worked but it didn't display text, but your .innerText did. So thanks for that.